# Why is the text-decoration showing in my client's mobile but not showing in my phone or browser?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

So I am facing a strange issue.

I made an email signature and I coded it in such a way that it doesn't display the text-decoration underline in the URL's of the signature.

I am not getting the text-decoration in any URL which means it is working.

However, my client is getting underlined URL's and also the underline is in different colour compared to the text...

What might be the issue? Is there any problem in the code?

I am attaching the code.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p style="color: #404040;"><strong>JOHN DO</strong></p>
      <p style="color: #404040;font-size:10px">Business Manager</p>
      <p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
      <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/email-icon.png"
             alt=""
             width="20"
             height="20" />&nbsp;<a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;"
           href="mailto:john@example.co.uk">john@example.co.uk</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/tel-icon.png"
             alt=""
             width="20"
             height="20" />&nbsp;8319831938</p>
      <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/address-icon.png"
             alt=""
             width="20"
             height="20" />&nbsp;4 Demo Address</p>
      <p style="text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/website-icon.png"
             alt=""
             width="20"
             height="20" />&nbsp;<a style="color: #808080;text-decoration:none;"
           href="https://www.example.co.uk">www.example.co.uk</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The signature shows fine in my side, but my client is getting underlined URLs and the underline is of a different colour.

Please note that the client is using an iPhone to view the signature using the native iOS email client.

Comment: What program is your client using to view the email. Could it possibly be due to whatever he is viewing it in is automatically underlining links as a feature?

Comment: Hi. He is using Apple iPhone. Using the native iOS mail client.

Comment: Do you have CSS in the head thats overwriting it? Showing full code might shed some light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I think your issue is that your client is viewing in an app (iOS email) that automatically underlines the links. There is a question on stack exchange that goes over this and how to turn it off:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124277/some-texts-automatically-underlined-in-iphone-5-with-ios-7-1
But as to your code, everything seems to be working as you intend, which can be viewed here:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6JDDU1ON9ED

Comment: OP has `text-decoration:none;` on the inline style. Don't think that is causing it?

Comment: Thanks! It helped me fix the issue. This helped me too: https://support.exclaimer.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360004382952-Removing-blue-underlines-in-iOS-email-signatures